# CLI 400 error deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Today I got a new error when trying to deploy my application to Google App Engine via the command line:

```
Updating module [default]...-ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Your app may not have more than 120 versions.
  Please delete one of the existing versions before trying to create a new version.
```

I am deploying to the top level using `--promote`, not creating other versions. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is also a way to do this via command line if that interests you.

> `gcloud preview app versions list`
>
> `gcloud preview app modules delete <module_name> --version=<version_number>`

---

**UPDATE 2017**
(see also [CLI 400 error deploying to Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40806335/2314737)
)

> List all versions:
>
> ```
> gcloud app versions list
> ```
>
> Delete versions v1 and v2:
>
> ```
> gcloud app versions delete v1 v2
> ```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/

Comment: Yes, this is much better!

Answer (score 21):

So I found a way to do it through the web GUI (https://console.developers.google.com). If you go to the "App Engine" tab there is a "Versions" option. Click that and it will take you to a listing of versions. Apparently one is created each time you deploy with `--promote` in addition to one for each version you deploy. These can be selected and then there is a trash can to click on them to delete them.

[image: GAE->App Engine->Versions]

While this is not the CLI solution I would have liked, it works.

Comment: This is the new location for versions: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?serviceId=default

Comment: the gui solution is better

Answer (score 13):

The previous answer for the command line is deprecated now. The alternative is the following:

To list all versions:

```
gcloud app versions list
```

To delete a version:

```
gcloud app versions delete v1 v2
```

More info on: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/delete

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for `cloudbuild.yaml` changes for this then here is the sample YAML config file

```
steps:
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: [ 'build', '-t', '<dockerRepository>', '.' ]

 - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
   args: ["app", "deploy"]

 - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
   entrypoint: 'bash'
   args:
   - '-eEuo'
   - 'pipefail'
   - '-c'
   - |-
     gcloud app versions list --format="value(version.id)" --sort-by="~version.createTime" | tail -n +6 | xargs -r gcloud app versions delete --quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last version only for a specific service. Keep in mind you could have several services in the same GCP.

Fist get the service name

```
gcloud services list --available
```

and then, remove it

```
gcloud app versions list --format="value(version.id)" --sort-by="~version.createTime" --service=SERVICE_NAME | tail -n -1 | xargs gcloud app versions delete --quiet
```